# error: assignment of member ai_family in read-only object

Tags: c, linux, sockets, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/// Global declarations:
const char  *hostNameOrIPAddress;
const char  *serviceOrPortNum;
const struct    addrinfo *hints;
struct addrinfo **resultOfGetAddrInfo;
int     socketFd;

int fillUpStructSockaddrIn ()
{
  hostNameOrIPAddress   = "127.0.0.1";
  serviceOrPortNum  = "1234";

  hints = malloc (sizeof (struct addrinfo*) * 10);
  hints->ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints->ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints->ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;

  if (getaddrinfo (hostNameOrIPAddress,
          serviceOrPortNum,
          hints,
          resultOfGetAddrInfo) != 0)
    // Indicate some error.
    return 1;

  return 0;
}

int main ()
{
  if (fillUpStructSockaddrIn() != 0)
    return 1;

  socketFd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

**

### Error message:

**

```
$ gcc server.c 
server.c: In function ‘fillUpStructSockaddrIn’:
server.c:35:3: error: assignment of member ‘ai_family’ in read-only object
   hints->ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;
   ^
server.c:36:3: error: assignment of member ‘ai_socktype’ in read-only object
   hints->ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
   ^
server.c:37:3: error: assignment of member ‘ai_flags’ in read-only object
   hints->ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
```

^

See the declaration of `getaddrinfo` here:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo

It needs a `const struct addrinfo *hints`.
How should I fill values in it?

If I don't malloc I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: don't declar them as const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration

```
const struct    addrinfo *hints;
```

declares `hints` as a pointer to a constant structure, i.e. one that is read-only and can't be changed.

---

Beside that, your allocation of `hints` is wrong, as you allocate ten pointers (which is 40 or 80 bytes depending on if you're on a 32 or 64 bit platform). You should allocate `sizeof(*hints)` bytes instead.

Also, the `malloc` call doesn't initialize the memory it allocates, which means the data in the member fields you do not initialize will be indeterminate and the `getaddrinfo` call will lead to [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of that. Clear the structure first, either by using [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) or by using [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset).

---

Actually you don't need to dynamically allocate that structure at all, just declare it as a normal local variable, and pass a pointer using the address-of operator `&`:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;

getaddrinfo(..., &hints, ...);
```

Right now you have a memory leak as you don't free the allocated memory. Using a structure (and not a pointer to the structure) you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: yes, I can see that, but "addrinfo"'s parameter wants that declaration. What point am I missing?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Yes, and that's because the `getaddrinfo` doesn't change the structure so the compiler may make some extra optimizations in that function and in the call. However, you have to change the structure, so you can't have it as constant, because then you can't set the fields you need.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `hints` as a pointer to a constant structure

```
const struct    addrinfo *hints;
```

So you not change data members of this structure and this code

```
  hints->ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints->ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints->ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
```

is wrong.

Even if the structure would not be constant the statements above are wrong because you did not allocate memory for structures. You allocated memory for pointers that have undefined values. So the program has undefined behaviour.

Also these statements

```
  if (getaddrinfo (hostNameOrIPAddress,
          serviceOrPortNum,
          hints,
          resultOfGetAddrInfo) != 0)
    // Indicate some error.
    return 1;

  return 0;
```

could be substituted at least for

```
return getaddrinfo (hostNameOrIPAddress,
              serviceOrPortNum,
              hints,
              resultOfGetAddrInfo) != 0;
```

And the program does not delete allocated memory.